# Can I reduce this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, prepared-statement

I have a table name `likes` which stores details about likes and dislikes for a post. To show the total number of likes for a post I need to take the diff between likes and dislikes. Now I am storing likes inside a column called `liked` which is of type `bool`. The idea is if liked then set it to true and disliked to false. My table looks like this,

```
| id | user_id | post_id | liked | 
| -- | ------- | ------- | ----- |
| 1  | 1       | 1       | true  |
| 2  | 7       | 1       | false |
| 3  | 12      | 1       | true  |
```

I used `SELECT liked, COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE post_id=1 GROUP BY liked;`, which returned

```
| liked | count |
| ----- | ----- |
| TRUE  | 2     |
| FALSE | 1     |
```

I want to take the difference between these two. Couldn't seem to find anything so I tried 
`SELECT SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE post_id=1 AND liked = true) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE post_id=1 AND liked = false));`

which returns what I want

```
| SUM |
| --- |
| 1   |
```

But still I feel like this query is not right. Is there a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution is to do the aggregation in two steps:

```
select max(cnt) - min(cnt)
from
(
  select count(*) cnt FROM likes WHERE post_id=1 GROUP BY liked
) dt
```

In your case, with only two different values you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select abs(count(*) filter (where c1 = true) - count(*) filter (where c1 = false))
from b
WHERE post_id=1
```

Comment: hey can explain what is the `dt` on your first solution. Is that something related to `psql` show tables `\dt` or another command ?

Comment: `dt` is just a table alias - which I use to chose for _derived tables_  - a subquery in the from clause.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two options:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE liked) - COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT liked)
FROM likes
WHERE post_id = 1;
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN liked THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)
FROM likes
WHERE post_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you... I didn't knew we could use conditional statements inside query.